# Change HttpTransportFactory cxf 2.7.3

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf

I'm trying to change the `HttpURLConnection` that the cxf `HTTPTransportFactory`uses.

Cxf (version 2.7.3) uses `HTTPTransportFactory` for http/https request.
The `HTTPTransportFactory` uses Conduit of type `URLConnectionHTTPConduit`.
`URLConnectionHTTPConduit` has method: `createConnection` which returns `HttpURLConnection`.
I need to replace `HttpURLConnection` with my own custom one, lets call it `CustomHttpURLConnection`.

I managed to change the `TransportFactory` that cxf uses by:

1. Creating class that extends `HTTPTransportFactory` : `CustomHTTPTransportFactory` (Right now this class is empty):

   ```
   public class CustomTransportFactory extends HTTPTransportFactory{
   }
   ```
2. Register `CustomTransportFactory` to the right Transport Id: in this case http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http

Here is my XML:

```
<beans:bean id="tranpo" class="CustomTransportFactory" lazy-init="false">    
    <beans:property name="transportIds">
                  <beans:list>
                 <beans:value>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"</beans:value>
          </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

However, I need to be able to register my `CustomHttpURLConnection` to the cxf transport `HTTPTransportFactory`.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a HTTPConduitFactory and register that in the context.   The HTTPTransportFactory will then use that to create the conduit instead of creating the default URLConnection based one.   This is how the HTTP Commons Async based conduit gets created and used.

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks a lot for your reply.
I went over AsyncHTTPConduitFactory implementation as you suggested and managed to understand how to implement custom ConduitFactory  suitable for my needs!

However I still don't know how to register my CustomConduitFactory to the HTTPTransportFactory.
1- You said: "Create a HTTPConduitFactory and register that in the context" what do you mean by saying context?
2- Could you please supply a code example for CustomConduitFactory registration? (either using code or using spring configuration)

Thanks again for your help :)