# Apache HttpClient 5 as transport option in Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, apache-httpclient-5.x

When using the [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs) in Java, we can create an instance of [Storage](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html) using a builder while specifying some transport options, as follows:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
     .setTransportOptions(myTransportOptions).build()
     .getService();
```

Is it possible to use an existing instance Apache HttpClient version 5 as transport options?

Comment: Have you tried to create a _CustomHTTPTransportFactory_? See https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$Builder/setTransportOptions?snippet=5ce6b89e2fd3800004c5dfe7

Comment: I believe this other Stackoverflow question can give you an idea (not identical to your issue) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573490/change-httptransportfactory-cxf-2-7-3